# Who will win the election?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

This is a challenge in which two people, 1 and 2, are running for office. People deterministically vote in certain ways in the world of 1 and 2, which can allow for the candidates to figure out the results before the election.

NOTE: this is not meant to refer to any outside elections or other political events.

Two people are running for office. We'll call these people 1 and 2. Because they both want to know if they will win the election, they decide to use their knowledge of people and some code to figure out what the result will be. Due to the want to minimize government spending, the code needs to be a short as possible.

**Your task:** Given a string of people based on how they are voting, output who wins the election.

There are five kinds of people in the fun and exciting world of 1 and 2:

- `A`: people who will definitely vote for 1.
- `B`: people who will definitely vote for 2.
- `X`: people who will vote for whoever the person to their left will vote for. If there is no person to their left, then they vote for whoever the person at their right will vote for. If it is not clear who the person to their right is voting for, then they do not vote.
- `Y`: people will vote the opposite of the person to their left. If there is no person to their left, then they vote opposite of whoever is at their right. If it is not clear who the person to their right is voting for, then they do not vote.
- `N`: people who do not vote.

This is evaluated from left to right.

**Example:**

Whoever is being "evaluated" is in lowercase, for clarity.

```
Input: `XXAYAN`
        xX      Votes for whoever their friend is voting for. Their friend has not decided yet, so it is unclear, so they do not vote.
        Xx      Person to left is voting "none" so votes "none."
          a     Votes for 1
          Ay    Since person on left is voting for 1, votes for 2.
            a   Votes for 1
             n  Does not vote
```

Final poll:

- 2 people voted for 1
- 1 people voted for 2
- 3 people did not vote

1 has the most votes, so 1 wins!

**Test cases:**

You may use other characters or values as input and output, as long as they are distinct. (For example: numbers instead of letters, different letters, lowercase letters, truthy/falsy or positive/negative (for output), etc.)

```
Input -> Output

"AAAA" -> 1
"BBBB" -> 2
"BBAXY" -> 2
"BAXYBNXBAYXBN" -> 2
"XXAYAN" -> 1
"AAAABXXXX" -> 2
"AXNXXXXAYB" -> 1
"NANNY" -> 1
"XA" -> 1
"YAB" -> 2
"XY" -> anything (do not need to handle test cases with no victor)
"AB" -> anything (do not need to handle test cases with no victor)
```

Comment: Can `NX` or `NY` appear?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, but not alone. (See last valid test case)

Comment: So, `ANNY` is the same as `AY`? Like, do we just remove `N`s?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ANNY is the same as just A NN. NX and NY become NN.

Comment: It might be clearer to use uppercase/lowercase instead of an asterisk.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Good idea, editing.

Comment: It might be worth specifying that `none` is the opposite of `none`, if the behavior for `NY` in the comments is correct.

Comment: IMHO there should be testcases beginning with `XA`, `XB`, `YA` and `YB`.

Comment: May input contains only 1 letters? e.g. "A", "X", "Y", "N".

Comment: Does the output have to be two **_distinct_** values, or can we for example output any positive integer if 1 wins and any negative integer if 2 wins?

Comment: @tsh Do you mean like an array of characters? If so, yes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It can be positive/negative. (I'll clarify in the challenge).

Comment: @Neil Yes, adding. Thank you.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony I mean, what the output for `"X"`? The behavior of a single `"X"` is confused to me.

Comment: @tsh for a single X, due to having no decided neighbors, would be N. But then no one wins. As such, you do not need to handle such a case. (I'll clarify the challenge when I get to a computer).

Comment: This is a really interesting logic challenge, thanks!

Comment: Do we have to handle single letter cases?

Answer (score 9):

## Java 8, <s>153</s> <s>141</s> <s>135</s> <s>131</s> 129 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,t,r=0,i=-1;for(;++i<l;r+=(t=a[i]=a[i]>4?t<3?t^3:3:a[i]>3?t:a[i])>2?0:3-t*2)t=a[i>0?i-1:i<l-1?i+1:i];return r;}
```

Uses an integer array as input with `A=1, B=2, N=3, X=4, Y=5` and outputs a positive integer (`>= 1`) if A wins, a negative integer (`<= -1`) if B wins, or `0` if it's a draw.

-18 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##nVbLbptAFN37K668wjF@AEatTLA1s@ui00rZgNJUmhiSTErAgiFWFHnbD@gn9kfcy/CInRiTdEaCGbDP4Z5z79Xc80c@ug9@7VYRzzL4ykX83AMQsQzTG74KgRVb9QBWGl4vr4APHHy27eElk1yKFTCIwYUdHy2eix9GLh9HYXwr73Spp@5UF@7IcG6SVHOGQ3EeOenQ1aTLL8WVuixmS3luLeVPa27N1QPcqMVgYS6nc2skz8yB@sNiuhQjY44gI2Mphri6ctJQ5mkMqbPdOb3JWe9LvM7lHIhr6EBdUwfmWjp47kwH37V733JZvZdpHhY/ueFRFvbOJhjQOr@OMKAqrsdEBPCAmmgXMhXxrQq@FOTiKZPhwzjJ5XiNr2QUa/3vafIogjAAGWYoF8/CbN5XYoF6pMXhBpSGz4au5nbgwJExmUCf4OjDaFGvNIIBUBQTsgQIbEScDY4hm7qaJ5ApjhK5XCHyFJFnCpmeRjb0mW4fxS6RiefX0ISU2CZiW93YChkZLLwXO1vdLcWlsBGaMo8S36Os4kAKypAJw2CKy0Kuz11cM0Qu8I0K/W0cnkd8UpEwRihhTSRGl/6Vs/jts3IecNTOUg/Hi720caLw2O6KoNDKqvFVLPt@Kw6PFQzEpzUJKwapWAqdzK5IrEIhnO1@M0St/C6WpUrG0Sw9Vi8/4ovkIQQeBEKKJObRuwrHVIliKAGKna3uL4mC2qJ5HqG@V3tIimxURpLKyk9NUpJTiWLr7cmiEsU/TJWPJoutjKzTXa1eGel7rEh5vDQcVGU9aVi6C7elGewVblVQTTMw3mCeMPA6ifNszzvY3InVHYRxAPkavwE4BCnftFla9ZWTHYt4L22lCbzM4BK8zcAToZcG1rI2oU@7UA3d7EAlddXRpiKMLlSrVYGm2ryPf6vVqQD7PwX0sjhs1SEOda6L0PMZq/VVFUhZ3SOspvxOsrT3uIrlVZM76HHvyhCrszTq2m5VZ/8gpA4MiqI@KrWeFu7x5DXOpYjGJE35UzaWSXnI0Phg2Ie/v/9AfxiPV7itzlvb3T8)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->{                      // Method with int-array parameter and boolean return-type
  int l=a.length,         //  Length of the input-array
      t,                  //  Temp integer, uninitialized
      r=0,                //  Result-integer, starting at 0
  i=-1;for(;++i<l         //  Loop `i` in the range [0, l):
           ;              //    After every iteration:
            r+=           //     Increase the result by:
             (t=a[i]=     //       Change `i`'th item in the array to:
                 a[i]>4?  //        If the `i`'th item is a 5:
                  t<3?    //         If `t` is 1 or 2:
                   t^3    //          Use `t` Bitwise-XOR 3 to invert it
                          //          (1 becomes 2; 2 becomes 1)
                  :       //         Else (`t` is 3, 4, or 5 instead):
                   3      //          Set it to 3
                 :a[i]>3? //        Else-if the `i`'th item is a 4:
                  t       //         Set it to `t`
                 :        //        Else (the `i`'th item is a 1, 2 or 3):
                  a[i])   //         Leave it unchanged
             )>2?         //      And if this new `i`'th value is 3, 4, or 5:
              0           //       Leave the result the same by increasing it with 0
             :            //      Else (it's 1 or 2 instead):
              3-t*2;      //       Increase it by 3 minus two times the `i`'th value
                          //       (which is 1 for 1; and -1 for 2)
         t=               //   Set `t` to:
           a[i>0?         //    If `i` is not the first item:
              i-1         //     Set `t` to the previous (`i-1`'th) value
             :i<l-1?      //    Else-if `i` is not the last item:
              i+1         //     Set `t` to the next (`i+1`'th) value
             :            //    Else (`i` is the first or last item):
              i];         //     Set `t` to the current item itself
  return r;}              //  Return the result
                          //  (positive if A wins; negative if B wins; 0 if it's draw)
```

Comment: `i=0;for(int n:a)i+=n<2?1:n<3?-1:0;return i>0;` saves a few bytes bytes.

Comment: Actually, `i=0;for(int n:a)i+=n>2?0:3-n*2;return i>0;` is even shorter.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! When I saw your first comment I was about to find something shorter, but you beat me to it with your second comment. ;)

Comment: [131 bytes](https://bit.ly/2U5tYTE) by merging the second loop in the first one. It doesn't feel right, though, and some test cases might have to be added...

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks! Been able to golf 4 more bytes by merging it some more with the temp variable. And what feels wrong about it? If you add a `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(a));` after the loop you can see it changed as you would expect (imo). What kind of test case would you think results in an incorrect result and due to what part of the code?

Comment: I was wrong with my comment: I felt like in a specific line, we modified `a[i+1]` or `a[i-1]` which would have lead to invalid data at some point if r is computed immediately rather than afterwards. But... it doesn't happen so no consequences! Which leads me to another golf that I'll post in a few minutes (edit: oops, no: no further golf)

Comment: 122 bytes: `a->{int l=a.length,t,r=l,i=-1;for(;++i<l;r+=~(a[i]=a[i]>4?t<3?t^3:3:a[i]>3?t:a[i])%3)t=a[i>0?i-1:i<l-1?i+1:i];return r<0;}` saves 9 more bytes if I count well. The `r=l` comes from a golf of `~(t=a[i]=...)%3` **`+1`**. And `~t%3+1` is the mapping with the ternary values (1 -> 1, 2 -> -1, 3 -> 0). Then I continued golfing to reach the result presented. I know it'll be hard to explain, so sorry in advance ;-)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Hmm, your 122 bytes version gives an incorrect result for one of the test cases. [Here is that single test case in the 131 bytes version](https://tinyurl.com/y75v54a3) and [here is that same test case in your 122 bytes version](https://tinyurl.com/y6ve4lz3). The conversion of the array is the same, so that's good, but the result is different. Probably because the items will not just be `1->1`, `2->-1`, `3->0`, but can also still be `4->0` or `5->0` when it starts with multiple `X`/`Y`, and your `~t%3+1` will map `4->-1` and `5->1` instead.

Comment: Oh, I somehow thought that those 4 and 5 were replaced by a 3. My bad.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Most indeed, but not all. :)

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>60</s> <s>50</s> <s>48</s> 59 bytes

```
l#(v:o)|v<2=v+v#o|n<-(3-v)*l=n+n#o
_#_=0
f x=rem(x!!1)2#x>0
```

Uses `1` for `A`, `-1` for `B`, `0` for `N`, `2` for `X` and `4` for `Y`. Returns `True` if `A` wins, else `False`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoMgEEX3nmIaNlqhAeqqkd6gJzDGkKqpKaJRQ1x4d6ujts1n8d9n@MNL9@/CmHk2xHe3JphcLJULHWkmGzP/ylxwNsqGljReRjLFvRJG1RW1P55OIpBkvPO51pUFBbVuHxn4bVfZAS5QBpB4kAiKSunimaDH@WNBJY0ORlhTvhjkaDMcJ@QCa3Tw3r4OyE17LLFgk8BGvODry0W4jzHQeV4NVWO1gaHoB3jqvuhxz/eT0c@KNJ0/)

On the recursive way down the input list we add `1` for every vote for `A`, `-1` for every vote for `B` and `0` for "no vote". `l` is the last vote, `v` the next. If `v=1`, `-1` or `0` (or `v<2`) we just add it to the sum. If `v` is "vote same" (`X` in the challenge, `2` for my solution) we keep and add `l` (`(3-2)*l` = `l`). If `v` is "vote opposite" (`Y` in the challenge, `4` for my solution) we first negate `l` (`(3-4)*l` = `-l`) and then add it. Base case is the empty list which starts the sum with `0`. Recursion is started with `l` set to `rem s 2` where `s` is the second element of the input list (`x!!1`). `rem s 2` maps `1` and `-1` to itself, all other values to `0`. Fix votes ignore `l` anyway [*] and `X` or `Y` get the right neighbor if it's a fix vote. If the overall sum is positive, `A` wins.

[*] this makes singleton lists with fix votes like `[1]` work, because due to Haskell's laziness access to the second element is never evaluated. Inputs like `[2]` fail with error, but don't have to be considered.

Comment: [This does not correctly handle X and Y without left neighbors](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0dZo8wqX7OmLM7Izsi2TLtMOb8mz0a3TCvHNk87TzmfK1453taAK02hwtZAucLO4H9uYmaegq1CbmKBb7yCRkFRZl6Jgp5CmqZCNJdCtKGOkY6uUawOmKlrpANh6iIJ60LFY/8DAA)

Comment: @Grimy: thanks for pointing out. Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl 5, <s>56</s> <s>80</s> <s>72</s> <s>65</s> 53 bytes

+26 bytes to handle the case X or Y in first position and A or B in second. output is `1` if 1 wins empty (false value in perl) otherwise.

```
s/^X(.)/$1$1/,s/A\KX|B\KY|^Y(?=B)/A/|s/B\KX|A\KY|^Y(?=A)/B/&&redo;$_=y/A//>y/B//
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##PYsxC4NADIX3/A4RD9oGh07FlmQVMicgdqlDQXriuQj@9l5zSz/IC3y8t0zrfM054ajNJWDVVi2eEtLQ68FDb8dozaPjgIRHQi6a/poCMtb1Or3irXp2u5fwvrvDnMkBdjxIDUqwKJMpC6iSkUApsTpAKuWTMQiJGPiEGMzPN9@4bO/4Sfm8zD8)

using `P` and `S` instead of `X` and `Y` allowing to use xor operation on characters, would save some more bytes

```
s/(?|^(P|S)(?=(A|B))|(A|B)\K(P|S))/P^$1^$2/e&&redo;$_=y/A//>y/B//
```

uses a branch reset group `(?|`..`|`..`)`, so that `$1` `$2` refering to corresponding group in branch.
Using `\0` and `\3` instead of `X` and `Y`

```
$_=s/^\W(?=(\w))|(\w)\K\W/$1.$2^$&/e?redo:y/A//>y/B//
```

[72 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYvBCsJADETv@YqCS6mgBgueSoXkKiwLvSQg9eIehGJL66XQb3dNCz6YCWRmhjh2l7TLpA6Z1g3MKIqhwSpN2BZhafYFLbzH0Lpz68qTKzEeJtye99tW@GcY83yMz75yj3pGQrzOyIgpkQFsmJEorMZemFTYgwgpeVhLLAaQ@PWSMnjyXsEmxKAm23z74fPq31M6Dt0P)

[65 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYuxCoNAEET7/QohIndFWBJIJRfZbQPHgc0uBNPEIiAqmka4b8/l9MHMwDAz98twS6dCXCjUtbChKIYW67SiaWJnQmytaZyhyNbGI56Po7UYuvLSlVfsq2rp31NdvtyGhHjfkBFTogxwJhuJwm7shUmFPYiQkod9xJIBEr8nKYMn7xXyhRg0K39@0/z9TOOazvPwBw)

[53 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYtBC4JAEIXv8zuW0IONFl4Kk5lrNFdnYLFLHgJJ0SCEfnvb7gfve5f35mEZ67ChGvrSH/Ec3L1Zsfdd1jaZ/@T5N9lffYeu2rtD73Y4tMvwmE4bEuJlQ0YMgSLAkShSgyQWZTJlAVUyEkgj1giQSmoyBiERg3ghBk1hAottTL9pfj@n1xqKeQzFrd6X1R8)

Comment: from my last understanding they are not counted any more

Comment: This does not correctly handle `X` and `Y` at the start of the string. Try `XBA` and `YAB`.

Comment: @Grimy, updated

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>78 75</s>  73 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers with: \$0\$ = N, \$1\$ = A, \$2\$ = B, \$4\$ = Y, \$8\$ = X.

Returns \$false\$ if the first candidate wins or \$true\$ if the 2nd candidate wins.

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((v,x,i)=>v+~~[,1,-1][p=x?x&3||~-x%7^(p&3||a[i+1]&3):0],p=0)<0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7RSsMwGIXv9xQh4EhYmjXuQhBTSR4g3iaUWkKaSmW2ZamlF6OvXhtRLzb3Xf3wcc5/3u1ogzs1/ZC0XeWXmi@WZ5aefPXpPEIjmUiDeTbu5jknjCSsyHs@PU/bw/k8J9Pdwyvq423zZseK7QE/pgXpeYqf0mXwYQAcBMAz4Lo2dEdPj90bqlFOKQ0F/bA9ctFCJWRpyrLUkDZt5aeXGjm8stnEEgTFCgS/YLDfgyQD7MfKlWt7/2eFNvCmXaVUWgqjpYKXVmthhII3/sZVUq/A/5qFVtEJ873tMquEUter2PIF)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
gFÐNè©2@iNx1.S-èDÄ2‹*D(‚®èNǝ]O
```

Uses an integer-array as input with `A=-1, B=1, N=0, X=2, Y=3` and outputs a negative integer (`<= -1`) if A wins, a positive integer (`>= 1`) if B wins, or `0` if it's a draw.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a/kmVdQWqJQlphTmlqsUFqcmmLFpeBoq2vIpeBkCyT8bA24FCJsjbgUIm2Nubj8S0uAyoFK/FLTE0syy1IVbBUcFcoz84q5FALyizOhQk5QIQMgO6UosVwp5n@62@EJfodXHFpp5JDpV2GoF6x7eIXL4RajRw07tVw0HjXMOrTu8Aq/43Nj/f//jzbSMdYxAkJdQyADSBjEAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##bU@/S8NAFN7vr3hkaStJSe6cxFATgqBDKri0xA6RhnIgrZim1SGQoThXR7GDW0tBcBInITf4f@QfiZe7i1SUdz@@99177/tuEoeXNCq1k/F1MoVZeJVEMSRxNDxA4NiGhcC1@eHbJoKejRH0bYJQN5nycl7iR6NwSmcR2ODAnI5jBGeTmCrKVZTJ8fAmnGsXCM3u2NLr7LPVoeb4bq@vFdnLqQZN9tmC4v4RtE45OmZLn63zDT6i/q3VPjfY2mMLXGQfe16zyJ7yV7b2v1Zp2i29jtfO3zzacNmWLWjDYdtGvmGLNC2y52pq/s4eWhzrZRAYll6vgQ6BpYuoIeexTmQmMSdNfouUCGBWz5hDwRiK2JmrV40i1AMWI2SIJqFnil4eRJVJPUMKipxIoBSJ/keViNk/5iQU9nd/pNqlaO1WecC/xKttCv3a1L/OB4Nv).

**Explanation:**

```python
g             # Take the length of the (implicit) input-list
              #  i.e. [3,1,3,3,2,0,1] → 7
 F            # Loop `N` in the range [0, length):
  Ð           #  Triplicate the list at the top of the stack
              #  (which is the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
   Nè         #  Get the `N`'th item of the list
              #   i.e. [3,1,3,3,2,0,1] and `N`=0 → 3
              #   i.e. [-1,1,-1,3,2,0,1] and `N`=3 → 3
     ©        #  Store it in the register (without popping)
   2@i        #  If it's larger than or equal to 2 (so either 2 or 3):
      Nx      #   Push `N` and `N` doubled both to the stack
              #    i.e. `N`=0 → 0 and 0
              #    i.e. `N`=3 → 3 and 6
        1.S   #   Compare the double integer with 1 (-1 if N*2<1; 0 if N*2==1; 1 if N*2>1)
              #   (So this will be -1 in the first iteration, otherwise it will be 1)
              #    i.e. 0 → -1
              #    i.e. 6 → 1
           -è #   Subtract that from the index, and index it into the list
              #    i.e. `N`=0 and -1 → 1 (first item, so get the next index)
              #     → [3,1,3,3,2,0,1] and 1 → 1
              #    i.e. `N`=3 and 1 → 2 (fourth item, so get the previous index)
              #     → [-1,1,-1,3,2,0,1] and 2 → -1
      D       #   Duplicate that value
       Ä2‹    #   Check if that value is -1, 0, or 1 (abs(i) < 2) (truthy=1; falsey=0)
          *   #   And multiply that with the value
              #   (remains the same if truthy; or becomes 0 if falsey)
      D(‚     #   Pair it with its negative (-1 becomes [-1,1]; 1 becomes [1,-1])
         ®è   #   And index the `N`'th value (from the register) into it (with wraparound)
              #   (if it was a 2, it uses the unchanged (first) value of the pair;
              #    if it was a 3, it uses the negative (second) value of the pair)
              #     i.e. [1,-1] and 3 → -1
              #     i.e. [-1,1] and 3 → 1
      Nǝ      #   And replace the `N`'th value with this
              #    i.e. [3,1,3,3,2,0,1], `N`=0 and -1 → [-1,1,3,3,2,0,1]
              #    i.e. [-1,1,-1,3,2,0,1], `N`=3 and 1 → [-1,1,-1,1,2,0,1]
 ]            # Close both the if-statement and loop
  O           # Sum the modified list (which now only contains -1, 0, or 1)
              #  i.e. [-1,1,-1,1,1,0,1] → 2
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(c=>x+=l=c%2|l*c/2,l=s[x=1]%2)|x>1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/RasMgGAXg@zyFCAWzGTO9FH5BH8BrJeQiuHRsuKbUUALrnj013drBmp7bD89//OiOXQqH9/1Y7YbXft7CnEAl9tntSQA1PUOEsBGn@BRqQSOkZgLebkR5mhSfxz6NCFBCoFAYdmmIPYvDG9mShjGW2p@aRcmXlhWnRnJq5Qt1UlAvK/HdhLbMKYqlimCdg9E1JaprVCnEf9Xk3Ku4qXYeP9SMxjqjvTMW/1fntNcWP7i7rDIuB681a2cX0/6y7e7t3@C1H62qKOYz)

Save 1 bytes, thanks to Shaggy.

---

- Input as integer array where N = 0, A = -1, B = 1, X = 2, Y = -2;
- Output 1 = Falsy, 2 = Truthy

Comment: Your TIO seems to output `0`, `1` and `3` instead of `1` and `2`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen But OP allowed truthy vs. falsy as output if i understand correctly. Falsy means 1 won the game, and truthy means 2 won.

Comment: Ah ok, forgot `3` is truthy in JS as well. I always think of `0`/`1` as falsey/truthy. And since we no longer need distinct outputs, `0` = 1 wins and `>= 1` = 2 wins is fine as well. So +1 from me.

Comment: It looks like you could save a byte using bitwise OR, instead of logical OR.

Comment: @Shaggy So strange. It works.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>95</s> 73 bytes

```python
lambda(v):sum([l for l in[2*int(v[1]/2)]for i in v for l in[i*l**(i%2)]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVBNi8MgEL37K4bAEk2TLsmx0AU99OjZkM0h21h2IJqgtrS/PqvpfrAPZsSZN@85Lo/wOdtmPcER3tdpMB/jQG/s4K@GdhNcZgcToO2aAm2gt67uXxvWpzLGMtz@GFhMRUHxJbZ7to76AucG6XkeNTsQiAjahwl9iE5dzvMyb2PIGCqGyPuNlOSW2WPA2ZaAQZtko@3VaDcETX9EvjUT8PLkHY@Q3P4aCU6Hq7O/klBBs/X1HQNlhKBZZhfAPzzZNkGrk2G8730Y0e6dHsZU9fRpucxLWmDbjT3fe04TiRNHHC6UwbbL4tKX/WvsMqjeINtlddVkXb0zw50atPREoywra1ZWNesZWXkEERExcdWSlIRUgrdKSKIUb7kkiSRUBOFKppO3gkguZUsUJy0XJE5y8QU)

---

- Input as integer array where N = 0, A = -2, B = 2, X = 1, Y = -1;
- Output negative = A, 0 = draw, positive = B
- If first input is X or Y, then 2*int(v[1]/2) maps second to itself or 0

Bug fix was required that added extra bytes, but converting to lambda thanks to @Stephen reduced it back to 95

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##RVBNb4MwDL3nV1iTJpIVKtFpl0ockkOPOQcxDqykmiUIKElRuz/PYrqPF9lRYvvZz/M9fk7udT1V7@vQjR99B8sxXEfecHSR799ehnRQ4AXw@WCHYAHFZfIw5Ajo4Atn3ixN2ba7pTkWZZsvohVrby9wPiA/T70VRwYJ0YY4YIhQQZPJLM/qZDqZSaaydksi5nkKGHFyOWC0IzWx7jpa30XLf0l@OAk0GeVVFVC3/wDB23j17o8SCjhscXvDyAVjOM6TjxDugW2i0FlqmN77EHt0e2@7nn4Df7Scp5kEbNrEY94zVVBOKvFpHQI2LbOnBcKTLNRTU@7G7sZHdPzEE4XIS5EXZdoUW2UCUwnJSVMzckobJWujNDNG1lIzSlImgUmj6Za1YlpqXTP6NLX5Bg "Python 3 – Try It Online") by removing whitespace and changing the function to a lambda function

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##VVDBbsMgDL3zFVakLdAmlZJjpU6CQ4@cibIcsoZqlgKJgFbtZb@eQbqt2pNshP38Hma@h8/J1ssRDvC@jL35GHq47v3F0BHOk4MR0LbXtupev6ouFTAW4Prs4WbcbCi@1Kxjy6DPcKqRnqZBsz2BiKB9GNGHaNDmPC/yJoaMoWKIvFtJSW2ePAacbAEYtEku2l6Mdn3Q9FfkRzMBzw/e4QDJ7dlIcDpcnP2ThBLqta9vGCgjBM08uQD@7sm6CFqdDON958OAdud0P6Sqpw/LeZrTAutu7PHeU5pInDjicKYM1l1mhzbQf41tBuUbZNusKuusrbamv1GDlh5plGVFxYqyir9HFh5BRERMXDUkJSGV4I0SkijFGy5JIgkVQbiS6eSNIJJL2RDFScMFiZNcfAM) by removing unnecessary parens and brackets, and using a bit mask,

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 70 bytes

```
AY
AB
BY
BA
}`(A|B)X
$1$1
^X(A|B)|^Y[AB]
$1$1
+`N|X|Y|AB|BA

.+|(?<=B)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xCgJBDET7@Y4T9jgQrldkprFLnSAea2FhYyGW8dvXXX1FwgyPkNf9/Xje2q6Uc20MUFBAxKcWpmbHtE4rNv@l3OJCXf/dUi09I6nsPvZLltPhqLk1dqBOH/RxzkPmYrgM7gwahiTvgG5jMwSjWcDHH18) Link includes test cases. Outputs `0` for a tie. Explanation:

```
AY
AB
BY
BA
```

Handle `Y` voters to the right of people with decided votes.

```
}`(A|B)X
$1$1
```

Handle `X` voters to the right of people with decided votes, and then loop back until all possible `Y` and `X` votes can be decided.

```
^X(A|B)|^Y[AB]
$1$1
```

Handle an initial `X` voter next to a decided vote, and also an initial `Y` voter next to a decided vote. As this voter will vote opposite to the decided vote, we can just delete both votes in this case.

```
+`N|X|Y|AB|BA
```

Delete any remaining no vote or undecided votes, and cancel out all pairs of opposing decided votes. Repeat until all possible votes are cancelled. In the case of a tie, nothing will be left, otherwise the remaining votes will all be of the same type.

```
.+|(?<=B)
```

Output `1` if there are any votes, but `2` if they are `B` votes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) 3.8+, 55 bytes

```
lambda v:[l:=v[1]&~1]and sum((l:=i*l**(i%2))for i in v)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDLasMwEKRXfcUSaC2ldsC-tARcKh1yKj7LpD64sUwXbNnYckgI6Y_0EijtP7VfU8lOHwO7Qrszs1q9frR789zo09sqfnwfTBncft5Uef1U5LBdrqtlvF2H2dVLmOW6gH6oKbU1nFfzOcXLiLGy6QABNWzZJP-6uC9UCZsI6aYpFFsSsDCqNxX2BmJYe9zzvdRGYkPaEF42kpxX2_RosNE-oFG1M1Z6qFWXG0V_TM6eDlhOvDgGN-2v4dApM3T61xICiMa-2qGhjBCs26Yz0O974kZXqJUbaO-L3hSoF53KC1ft6Xlk27Rug3E5Nr534xSOYyUdtpTBtEvboTa09A7_e0cI7uAwC4Notg6v63xHa9R0Ra0t80PmByHLjt75I0-fD9yCCAubuEyJSyKRgqdSJERKnvKEOJKQFoTLxJ08FSThSZISyUnKBbFKLibTbw)

Port of [ABridgeTooFar's Python 2 solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/179704/85334), since we took the time [in TNB](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60745317#60745317) to figure out why and how that list comprehension does anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

### Python <del>3</del> 2, <del>125</del> <del>121</del>  117 bytes

(Thanks to Jonathan Frech)

```
def f(x):
    for i,v in enumerate(x):n=x[i-(i>0)];x[i]=(v>3)*n+abs(n-1)*(v<0)+x[i]*(0<v<4)
    print x.count(1)>x.count(0)
```

Using tab indentation

Input: list of `int`s where 'A'=1, 'B'=0, 'X'=4, 'N'=3, 'Y'=-1, so "AAAA" is `[1, 1, 1, 1]` and "XXAYAN" is `[4, 4, 1, -1, 1, 3]`.

`[{'A': 1, 'B': 0, 'X': 4, 'N': 3, 'Y': -1}[c] for c in s]` will convert the strings to the needed input format.

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5Na4NAEEDP@iuGXNw1pmi0HxgV1oPHPfWwIh6sUSoka/ALS@lvtyNpTOxc3sLbYd7lq/us5X6ajkUJJRmpqypl3UBlDFBJKGR/LpqsK65Gkf6YVDtSBSZND/hMfTIENtXllsi6A0l1Mngm3c5KJ6Y3eA5VlUtTyQ7Gp7zuZUcsGtyeJp0i8OGUnT@OGbQuFiTfGtNcsAzQQqSJFEgHyZE2MkburJ8kT2FOzefQNqXq9Qxuvjd9YRwgIhuGs7mZvQFRdmr/VIizKPufYiJenLN2qEIuQhaLkC9/nh@PCsFidncvq/25KBQ4i39dBQs@Sxbf294ePWecY9r0Cw) (Thanks to Jonathan Frech for the suggestion)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. I would recommend using [TIO](https://tio.run/##bY9Bi4MwEIXP@isGTwl0i25vsgrJocecE8RDuiZ0oE1KjMX99TbFFnZx32ne9@YxzO0nnr07LMtgLFgy0zrPrA@AuzugA@Omqwk6mjXJXDN3BHeAHxXtsC37PkG0cG8P9dxh37iX/ypXr08jcWk5z4KJU3Aw77/95CKpaPseS7ocoYGLvp4GDWMNZa7H0YQIR1KwpIJC00D1i/KklX7@oUyqf3CiXEjOlORiG0vJFBPbG8/LXCZtK0yKZ8AU39YEE0K98S1gerAQHtYF9A6sxosZ9gVdHg), as it nicely formats your code. Furthermore, I do not quite understand your input format. You may have to ask the OP about its validity.

Comment: As a golfing tip, `(i, i-1)[i>0]` should be equivalent to `i-(i>0)`.

Comment: Furthermore, your `if`s could probably become `x[i]+=(v>3)*n+abs(n-1)*(v<0)`. You can then save on indentation by moving the now non-compound statement (using `;`) on the same line as the `for`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Thank you very much; I hope I explained the input better

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>187</s> 156 bytes

Really not that competitive with the other python answers on this, but I had some good ideas for using dicts to make an answer that actually takes string inputs, and it didn't turn out horribly long.

```python
def E(s):
 r,g,*v=range(len(s)),lambda**d:d.get(s[i],0),*s
 for i in r:v[i]=g(A=1,B=-1)
 for i in r:v[i]=g(X=1,Y=-1)*v[(i-1,i+1)[i<1]]or v[i]
 return sum(v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xa8MwEIV3/wqRSVLlEtGlmHo4QVbNJ4wHFyuOIJGN7Bjy651zhoJC3/h9d7w3PZbLGL@@p7RtvT@zE59FVbCkBiXXOnVx8PzqI1Ghrt3tt@@k7Kv@c/ALn5vQqqNQci7YeUwssBBZqlbC9cCh1srUpRb/SSTpdinXhodSq/ChRRN@dNvS7X5EG/xyT5HN9xtfxTalEBd@4gegHIQo/oChvAFAlxMCxqIBh8ZmBhEc5GgvMEjJKdqdgcu7LFibd2G@zkH@8LbsZbcn)

Edit -21 bytes: Some beautifully horrific abuse of python by @Unrelated String

Loops through the input twice to fill out an output list containing the vote of each person (`1` for `A`, `-1` for `B`, `0` for no vote), and filling out the `X`s and `Y`s on the second loop. I thought I could do it with one loop, but irritatingly that fails on an `X` or `Y` at the beginning of the string, as it hasn't processed the following vote yet. The return value is positive if candidate 1 wins, and negative if candidate 2 wins. (The absolute value of it also happens to be the margin of victory)

Comment: [164](https://tio.run/##ZY4xa8MwEIV3/wqRxZKjlIguxUTDCbJqPmE8lEZJBY1iZMUQQn67e@5QqvSN37t37w23/HmJr29DmueDP7I9H0VbsSSbSaf3ePL8y0diQjZjxY6XxAILkaV26kKvD@Ejc9BKGr1R0uqteDn5zEfy5Fb8v7/XWLdK1q5uN@rx97aZOh7oR1gr0YWd6nuKLhna4vM1RTZez3wS85BCzHzPV0BaCVH9AkN6AoCuJASMRQMOjS0cRHBQoqXAIKmkaBcGruyyYG3ZheU6B2XgadmPO38D) with the `dict` constructor, aliasing `range(x)` (hard to remember it's not a mutable iterator sometimes!), fiddling with the `eval` a bit, and initializing `v` a bit more messily.

Comment: ...although the `dict` constructor bit doesn't matter if you remove the `N` key, since it's 0 anyways

Comment: [this has NO right to work](https://tio.run/##bY4xa8MwEIV3/wqRSVLlEtGlmHo4QVbNJ4wHFyuOIJGN7Bjy651zhoJC3/h9d7w3PZbLGL@@p7RtvT@zE59FVbCkBiXXOnVx8PzqI1Ghrt3tt@@k7Kv@c/ALn5vQqqNQci7YeUwssBBZqlbC9cCh1srUpRb/SSTpdinXhodSq/ChRRN@dNvS7X5EG/xyT5HN9xtfxTalEBd@4gegHIQo/oChvAFAlxMCxqIBh8ZmBhEc5GgvMEjJKdqdgcu7LFibd2G@zkH@8LbsZbcn)

Comment: holy s#!7 @UnrelatedString thats some *beautiful* abuse of python right there

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 54 bytes

```
s/^\W(?=(\w))|(\w)\K\W/$1^$2^$&/e&&redo;$_=y/A//>y/B//
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYs9C8MwDER3/Q4TkqGoH3QKaZHWgtZIYNKlGQqhNkmhGPrb69oP7t1yF@d1OeeEauj3/oR93nDyY3sdWv/pum@1v/kR3WFyx8k1ODfNOj9C7@5DQkK8JGTEnKkAXCgiNahiUSZTFlAlI4E6Yi0AqdQmYxASMSgXYtAaJrDSxvQL8f0Mry3v4vIH)

Uses `A` for `A`, `B` for `B`, `N` for `N`, `\0` for `X` and `\3` for Y (the last two being literal control chars). The trick is that `A` bitwise-xor `\3` equals `B`, and vice-versa.

Comment: it uses many ideas of my answer, i wasn't sure we can use non printable character as input and output, except i didn't realize the benfit of using backslash character classes

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6) - 133 bytes

```
a=>(i=($=_=>'AB'.search(_)+1)(a[1],o=0),[...a].map(v=>(r=['NAB','NBA']['XY'.search(x)],p=r?r[i]:v,i=$(p),o+='NA'.search(p))),o>0?1:2)
```

Takes in a string with the format given in the OP and returns *1* if candidate 1 won and *2* otherwise (I'll admit it, I'm even-biased).